# Not able to retrieve if the parameter starts with zero when passing from jquery to my webmethod

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

My Problem looks really strange, I am calling an `Autocomplete.asmx` web method from jQuery. Thew first time the first parameter, `0`, is passing, and the second time the zero is getting replaced, instead of `0`, any other numbers are getting displayed.

**Aspx:**

```
  function SearchText() {

                    $('#<%=txtphoneno.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            Search();
                        }
                    });
                }

                //-->loadtop 5 jobs 
                function Search() {

                    var callid = $('#<%= txtphoneno.ClientID%>').val().toString();
                  //  alert(callid);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "../HttpHandler/Autocomplete.asmx/GetCallername",
                        data: "{'callerid':" + callid + "}",
                                     dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            //response(data.d);
                            //  alert(data.d);
                            $('#<%=txtname .ClientID %>').removeClass('text-label');
                            $('#<%=txtname .ClientID %>').addClass('lbls');
                            $('#<%=txtnote .ClientID %>').removeClass('text-label');
                            $('#<%=txtnote .ClientID %>').addClass('lbls');


                            document.getElementById('<%=txtname .ClientID %>').value = data.d[0];

                            document.getElementById('<%=txtnote .ClientID %>').value = data.d[1];

                            if (data.d != 'User Doesnt Exist') {

                                var param = $('#<%= txtphoneno.ClientID%>').val();
                                          $("#<%=IframeJobHistory.ClientID%>").show();

                                          LoadHistoryDetails(param);
                                      }
                                      else {
                                          // $("#<%=IframeJobHistory.ClientID%>").hide();

                                      }
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            // alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
```

** CS Code AutoComplete.Asmx**

```
[WebMethod ]    
        public string [] GetCallername(String callerid)
        {
            ..............................
                return CallerDetails;

        }
    }
```

In the `String callerid`, the first time when the user enters `0` I am getting back `0`, but second time when the user enters any number I am getting the number but the Zero disappears.

If i use any other number,apart from zero things are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using zero try to use -1

Comment: Hi, The User will type the caller id like 04444... something like this.so cant add -1

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , I don't know what you missed  , But I know the simple one 
solution for your issue .

> Just add this code for dynamically add 0 if the first value is not zero, Otherwise it's diaplayed your default value

Put break point and check

```
    [WebMethod ]    
    public string [] GetCallername(string callerid)
    {
       string Filteredcallerid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(callerid) ? callerid.Substring(0, 1) : "";
       callerid = Filteredcallerid != "0" ? "0" + callerid : callerid;
       return CallerDetails;

    }
```

Comment: I Tried if i add zero also that zero is also missing,it looks like the string doesnt starts with zero.but if i add other numbers they are getting displayed really strange

Comment: My solution like , If user entered number started with zero , Then it's display that number, and if entered zero but the zero when disappearing  ,at this time add zero . I think all time the user entered zero ? right ?

Comment: No some Times ,the number will start without Zero. any way i tried by adding Zero as the starting Number but its getting disappeared, if the starting number is other than Zero Then its available.